# Como ordenar um Collection de acordo com a Data e Hora no C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expressões-lambda

Preciso ordenar a Collection PessoasSituacoesAnalises pelo campo DataHoraAnalise (Formato DateTime), de maneira que seja ordenado de forma descendente por Data e Hora?

Não está ordenando... Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

```
public Pessoa GetJoinById(int id)
{
    var pessoa = Db.Pessoa.Find(id);

    Db.Entry(pessoa)
         .Collection(x => x.PessoasGenericos)
         .Query()
         .Include(x => x.Empresa)
         .Include(x => x.PessoasSituacoesAnalises)
         //.ThenInclude(x=> x.PessoaSituacaoTipo)
         .Load();

         return pessoa;

 }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tá difícil entender seus objetos.

Comment: Atualizei o post @Edney com parte do diagrama de classes. Estou usando o EF Core 2.1 e estou fazendo um get no repositório. Estou incluindo algumas tabelas, mas em especial, a tabela "PessoaSituacaoAnalise", precisa vir ordenada de forma descendente por Data e hora usando o campo DataHoraAnalise.

Comment: Parece que o problema está em fazer o ordenamento dentro do Include. Tenta fazer a query sem ordenar, chamar .ToList() e ordenar a lista.

Comment: Como o Edney comentou, você está ordenando apenas o seu include, e não o resultado total da query. Mas está confusa a relação das classes, apresente a as suas entidades (o código, não o desenho). [MCVE]

Comment: @MasterJR Conseguiu resolver ou desistiu?

Comment: Deixei pausado, mas ainda não resolvi @Leandro Angelo.